# How to access database using Hibernate-provided JPA extensions on struts2 framework?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa, struts2

I have been learning struts 2 based development, and having a real hard time accessing database's basic CRUD functionality using Hibernate-provided JPA extensions on struts 2.

I am using maven as the build tool, and I have been stuck here for a week or something.

I think that I am unable to fit in the persistence.xml file or some mapping file required, but can someone give me the steps required to go by in order to access database using the mentioned technologies.

I am using MySQL database and given below is the code:

**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLNSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="APP">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.app.classes.User</class>
        <mapping-file>User.hbm.xml</mapping-file>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/APP" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="9250864418" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
</persistence>
```

**User.java (Object Model class)**

```
package com.app.classes;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.io.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "APP_USER", schema = "APP")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String emailId;
    private String password;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    public String getEmailId() {
        return emailId;
    }

    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Column(name = "USER_PASSWORD")
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

**BaseAction.java (Action class)**

```
package com.app.action;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Preparable;
import com.service.UserService;

public class BaseAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<User>, Preparable {
    private User user;
    private String emailId;
    protected UserService service;

    @Override
    public User getModel() {
        return user;
    }

    public void getEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }

    public String setEmailid() {
        return emailId;
    }

    public void setUserService(UserService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    public void prepare() throws Exception {
        if (emailId == null || "".equals(emailId)) {
            user = new User();
        } else {
            user = service.findByEmailId(user.getEmailId());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

**UserServiceImpl class(class implementing service)**

```
package com.app.service;

import org.hibernate.Session;

import java.util.*;
import com.app.classes.User;
import com.app.classes.HibernateUtil;
import javax.persistence.*;

public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    private EntityManager em;

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    public void save(User user) {
        if (user.getEmailId() == null) {
            // new
            em.persist(user);
        } else {
            // update
            em.merge(user);
        }
    }

    private EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public User findByEmailId(String emailId) {
        return em.find(User.class, emailId);
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app id="starter" version="2.4" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Struts 2 - Maven Archetype - Starter</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Filters -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>action2-cleanup</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ActionContextCleanUp</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>action2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>action2-cleanup</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>action2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Listeners -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <!-- Servlets -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dwr</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>uk.ltd.getahead.dwr.DWRServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jspSupportServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.struts2.views.JspSupportServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>5</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dwr</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <!-- Welcome file lists -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**Struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC 
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <package name="myPackage" extends="struts-default">
    <default-interceptor-ref name="paramsPrepareParamsStack" />
        <action name="base" class="com.app.action.BaseAction">
            <result>/jsp/user.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

I did as sourav said, but there is still some problem in bean creation, here spring is unable to create the bean defined in the application context.xml file. This bean is basically for my UserServiceImpl class, so I have provided the server stack trace,any suggestion would be helpful

```
    SEVERE: Context initialization failed
```

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in file [/home/ankur/Desktop/app/target/classes/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.app.service.UserServiceImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/util/file/ArchiveBrowser$Filter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:883)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:839)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.doStart(Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.java:115)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginServer.start(Jetty6PluginServer.java:132)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:441)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:383)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyRunMojo.execute(AbstractJettyRunMojo.java:210)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6RunMojo.execute(Jetty6RunMojo.java:184)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.app.service.UserServiceImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/util/file/ArchiveBrowser$Filter
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:115)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:61)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:877)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/util/file/ArchiveBrowser$Filter
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:119)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:83)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:60)
    at com.app.service.UserServiceImpl.(UserServiceImpl.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:100)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.util.file.ArchiveBrowser$Filter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClassDirect(RealmClassLoader.java:195)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadClass(DefaultClassRealm.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadClass(DefaultClassRealm.java:274)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClass(RealmClassLoader.java:214)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:401)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:363)
    ... 66 more
2011-07-11 17:49:00.008::WARN:  Failed startup of context org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext@7e5619{/app,/home/ankur/Desktop/app/src/main/webapp}
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in file [/home/ankur/Desktop/app/target/classes/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.app.service.UserServiceImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/util/file/ArchiveBrowser$Filter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:883)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:839)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.doStart(Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.java:115)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginServer.start(Jetty6PluginServer.java:132)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:441)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:383)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyRunMojo.execute(AbstractJettyRunMojo.java:210)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6RunMojo.execute(Jetty6RunMojo.java:184)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.app.service.UserServiceImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/util/file/ArchiveBrowser$Filter
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:115)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:61)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:877)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/util/file/ArchiveBrowser$Filter
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:119)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:83)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:60)
    at com.app.service.UserServiceImpl.(UserServiceImpl.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:100)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.util.file.ArchiveBrowser$Filter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClassDirect(RealmClassLoader.java:195)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadClass(DefaultClassRealm.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadClass(DefaultClassRealm.java:274)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClass(RealmClassLoader.java:214)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:401)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:363)
    ... 66 more
2011-07-11 17:49:00.016::WARN:  Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in file [/home/ankur/Desktop/app/target/classes/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.app.service.UserServiceImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/util/file/ArchiveBrowser$Filter:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.util.file.ArchiveBrowser$Filter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClassDirect(RealmClassLoader.java:195)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadClass(DefaultClassRealm.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadClass(DefaultClassRealm.java:274)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClass(RealmClassLoader.java:214)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:401)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:119)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:83)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:60)
    at com.app.service.UserServiceImpl.(UserServiceImpl.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:61)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:877)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:839)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListen

Comment: What specifically is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you try to connect your DB through the JPA,

1.You are saying you try to connect through JPA persistence API so there should not be any hbm file,that you specify in the persistence .xml file.

2.In the service class you try to access data through the entitymanager,You have not provide/load the persistence.xml from where the jpa load data.As i have seen you have written a getter/setter method,So are you using Spring injection to inject the entitymanager property.

So i think first look in to the JPA part and test it then connect it with Struts2.
Try this line to create entitymanager.

```
 emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyJPAApplicationPU");
 em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

Here the "MyJPAApplicationPU" is the persistence unit name.that is define in the persistence.xml file,for you its "APP".

Answer (score 0):

Ok ankur,just provide your application-context xml file,
Actualy this error happend when factory not able to load any bean id in the xml.

One thing i suggest you that you are using interface injection,so in your UserServiceImpl you need to inject the referance property that is required is entitymanager object

have you written your application contex like this

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean id="userService" class="quickstart.service.UserServiceImpl" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/xyz" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

2.If yes then in your chek your **web.xml** the context loader

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

3.and also use @PersistenceContext

```
@PersistenceContext
```

public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em)
         {
       this.em = em; 
         }

Comment: Thanks sourav, its because of your help I successfully accessed the database, but then i made some changes and now again I am not able to connect to the database. i have revert back the state of the application as it was, when it was working. but still not able to access db. The problem is when application execute user=service.findByEmailId(emailId), to search for the user in the database, I get the following stack trace,where AuthAction is action                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException
 com.app.action.AuthAction.prepare(AuthAction.java:40)

Comment: have you checked that the value you are passing through service is not null.or have u created the getter /setter method on the action class for emailid?